Additional GET parameters in link that is using sms:// scheme
In our project our staff send SMS with invoice info to our customers. As they are using android tablet, we added a button for them in our app with a link, that looks like this
<a href="sms:+<phone_number>?&body=Invoice%20number:<inted invoice number>.
Invoice%20
link:http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.test%2F<some_internal_url>3Finvoice_id%3D<inted_number>
%26phone%3D<phone_number>%26ch%3D1%26dba%3D1">Send invoice to the customer</a>

Body parameter without encoding (for usage in link it will be encoded with php's urlencode):
Invoice number:123.
Invoice link: http://domain.test/path1/path2?invoice_id=123&phone=+12345678910&ch=1&dba=1

The problem is: on iOS and some Android versions this link perfectly opens in default messaging app. But in the most of Android versions and Harmony OS, it shows text without GET parameters after invoice_id, so link looks like this:
http://domain.test/<some_internal_url?invoice_id=<inted_number>

That's all, no phone, ch and dba parameters.
My question is: it is possible to handle these parameters in Android correctly?
I've already tried to rename phone to some random param name, but, no luck.
UPD. Question updated: more convenient body parameter

Having query parameters on a URL that itself is a query parameter on another URL seems risky. For example, I have tried three online URL decoders and none can handle what you are trying to supply as input. You might consider providing an improved sample link, one that actually works on iOS (e.g., redacting by supplying fake characters of the same type as what would be there, rather than having < and > in incompatible spots).
